# Multiple dropdown select with jquery and mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a search function in PHP and jQuery. I have 3 dropdowns that are loaded from a MySQLdatabase. When a user selects 1 of the dropdowns it has to affect the other dropdown values.

I made it working for the seperate values but I'm stuck when they select 2 or 3 dropdowns. I worked with the && operator but this doesn't work. Can someone please take a look what im doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    if( $(("#IndID").change) && $(("#CatID").change)) {
        $("#ProdName").load("scriptp.php?c3=" + $("#IndID").val() + $("#CatID").val());

        if( $(("#IndID").change) && $(("#ProdName").change)) {
            $("#CatID").load("scriptc.php?c=" + $("#IndID").val() + $("#ProdName").val());
            $("#IndID").change(function() {
                $("#CatID").load("scripti.php?c=" + $("#IndID").val());
            });

            $("#CatID").change(function() {
                $("#ProdName").load("script.php?cc=" + $("#CatID").val());
            });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are handling the events wrong , .change doesnot provide you the notification for the event so you cannot use it in if condition . Please provide the html also , i will try for the solution . If you can please create fiddle here [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)